# Время в нужном формате

Tags: android, xml

Дата приходит в таком формате:

```
<to_time_formatted>2018-05-10 21:37:00</to_time_formatted>
```

Вопрос - как разобрать её для вывода в `21:37`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если длинна получаемого поля известна и постоянна, можно сделать так:

```
String time = getString(R.string.to_time_formatted).substring(10,16)
```

`getString` можно заменить на ваш способ получения строки.

Индекс "выреза" можно сделать относительным `subString(date.indexOf(":")-2,date.indexOf(":")+3);`

`indexOf(":")` - он найдет первое двоеточие (которое у вас во времени) и возьмет первые две цифры до и две цифры после.

Comment: Если получаю так:

    public String getTo_time_formatted() {
                String time = to_time_formatted.substring(10,15);
             
                return time;
            }

  , то остается 14:4  то есть обрезается одно цифра...

Comment: РАботает в таком виде:   public String getTo_time_formatted() {
            String time = to_time_formatted
                    .substring(to_time_formatted.indexOf(":")-2,to_time_formatted.indexOf(":")+3);

           
            return time;
        }  Благодарю

Comment: изменил ответ `substring(10,16)` - так тоже ничего не обрежется